# How do I make snakemake rebuild missing inputs?

Tags: snakemake

Is there a way for snakemake to behave like make in cases when inputs are missing?
Is the current behavior of snakemake a bug or a feature?

```
$ ls
b  Makefile  Snakefile

$ cat Makefile
b: a
    touch b
a:
    touch a

$ make -n
touch a
touch b


$ cat Snakefile
rule b:
   input: "a"
   output: touch("b")

rule a:
   output: touch("a")


$ snakemake -n
Building DAG of jobs...
Nothing to be done.

$ snakemake -v
5.20.1
```

Answer (score 4):

In your case, `a` is only intermediate output to generate `b`. Since `b` is already there, the Snakefile will do nothing.

You can either call snakemake with the `-F` parameter to redo intermediate steps

```
snakemake -n -F
```

or define a target rule where both `a` and `b` are designated as final output

```
rule all:
   input: "a", "b"

rule b:
   input: "a"
   output: touch("b")

rule a:
   output: touch("a")
```

Comment: Not the OP, but as per the snippet shown, file `b` doesn't already exist. `make` was run only in dry-run mode, and therefore no files would have been created. Of course, explicitly showing `ls` output would remove any doubts here. In addition, lack of `rule all` in OP's code wouldn't cause the problem, as [snakemake executes the first rule in Snakefile](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#targets-and-aggregation), by default.

Comment: It's easy to miss, but the `ls` is in the first line of the snippet and shows that `b` is there. And so, the first rule is not executed. It's always a good idea to have a pseudo-rule in my opinion. It helps keeping an overview of the final desired outputs.